# Do we have to create an application for iPhone and iPad separately?

Tags: iphone, ipad, mobile, native

Ok, I just got into application development as the world is driving me crazy with mobile stuff. When creating an application do we have to create/code iPhone and iPad version of application separately and wrap them together or what is it like? I really dont want to use 2x button on iPad and want it to look different even.

Answer (score 1):

There are a TON of questions on SO related to this, and without really knowing what your particular situation is it would be difficult to point you to a single one that will address your needs. However, this [blog post](http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=563), though over a year old now, should help you out a bit.

The [recommendation from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) if you're starting from scratch is to create a Universal application in XCode and then simply create two versions of your UI (one for iPhone and one for iPad).